# string to parse out a URL

Tags: c#, regex

Got this regex string from "JavaScript: the good parts" (pp. 66).  Can't get it to work.  Can anyone see what is wrong with it?

```
/^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/
```

it's supposed to split up a string like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

into constituents: scheme, slash, host, port, path, query, hash

btw: this regex needs to be generic... it's going to be used on different "schemes"

Comment: Generic? Schemes? What do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried doing this using System.Uri class?

Comment: could you post a sample input and any error messages or what the output actually is?

Comment: scheme = http / https / ftp / etc

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  It doesn't split the string at all.

Comment: @Matias Fiedemraizer: thanks for the tip.  so that's new Uri(someString).  Then you can access different components via dot notation.  e.g. .scheme / .etc

Comment: @sgtz Absolutely, check my answer, you can check Uri class properties :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this isn't your goal, but why don't you use `System.Uri` class?

It has what you want and it parses raw URI/URL(s).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: +1: ty.  this is the answer I'll use, but I'm still mystified by the regex expression.  Thanks for mentioning this approach.  Since its a regex question, do we need a regex answer, or is another answer allowed under SO usage?

Comment: SO is for answering questions. There's no problem if you asked for some solution but you got another which satisfies your requirements. One marks an answer as correct one if it solves the problem, and others, someday, may answer why your regex isn't working because this question is going to keep opened :)

Answer (score 1):

your question is tagged with `c#`, so why don't you just use the [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class?

eg

```
string s = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
Uri uri = new System.Uri(s);

string scheme = uri.Scheme;
string host = uri.DnsSafeHost;
// etc
```

Comment: +1: ty that's an answer that I'll be using... but I'm still mystified by the regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Javascript try

```
result = subject.match(/\b(https?|ftp):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/ig);
```

Comment: also, it is not generic for the scheme.  Looks like it is tied to https / ftp

Comment: Didn't see the meantion of C# only Javascript and Sgtz is correct its limited to https and ftp but you can easily expand it to add others

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know, what is the meaning of all parts of regex, but the last # character should be escaped by backslash.

```
/^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:\#(.*))?$/
```

Comment: used @"..." to define the string, so no escaping needed.

Comment: @sgtz Yes it is. You have to escape regex character not C#. Questionmark is regex metacharacter - makes preceding element optional.